# How to make array of objects in Twig?

Tags: php, arrays, object, twig

I'm new to TWIG...
Within a TWIG template, I need to create a new array of objects that is a subset of an existing array of objects (products).

So far, I have this:

```
{% set onlyLimitedAmtProds = [] %}
{% for product in products %}
    {% if product.in_stock_amount < 3 %}
        {% set onlyLimitedAmtProds = onlyLimitedAmtProds|merge(product) %}
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

The above generates an error of:
"The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes; array and object given."

I'm not sure of the syntax to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to merge array `onlyLimitedAmtProds` with object `product`. But merge function works only with two arrays. You need to merge with an array of one element: `merge([product])`.